# Jmeter is retaining value of "result variable name" in next thread loop

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I have a jmeter thread group which uses transaction controller & a while loop controller inside that to run a query to fetch a token from db. while loop controller has below condition -
${__javaScript("${db_data}".indexOf("replay") == -1,)}

This variable db_data is retrieved with a select query result & loop will run until a value is there (inserted with a http request at the start of thread group). My issue is that until loop count in the thread group is 1; it works fine but once loop count is 2 or more, 2nd iteration is breaking the while loop instantly. How can I ensure that each thread loop initiates with variable db_data as null & does not retain the value inserted in previous run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because on 2nd and next iterations your `${db_data}` JMeter Variable contains `replay` hence While Controller's condition isn't met anymore.

The solution is to **reset** the variable in the beginning of the iteration, one of the possible options is adding i.e. [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) as the first sampler in your Thread Group and use the following code:

```
SampleResult.setIgnore()
vars.remove('db_data')
```

It will "clear" the `${db_data}` variable so your test will be able to re-enter the While Controller on subsequent iterations.

In the above snippet **vars** stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, see the JavaDoc for all available functions and [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) for more information on this and other JMeter API shorthands which are available for JSR223 test elements.

Also I would recommend reconsidering using __javaScript() function, its performance is a big question mark, moreover there is no [JavaScript language support in latest Java versions](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/372) so it might be a good opportunity for switching to [__jexl3()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) or [__groovy()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) function instead.